# Scipy tf2zpk and math operation

Tags: scipy

I have a function "ntf" which is defined in zero, pole, gain format

```
num = [1, -2, 1]
den = [1, -0.5, 0.16]
ntf = tf2zpk(num, den)
```

I want to perform the operation

```
L = 1/ntf - 1
```

However, the output of tf2zpk is a tuple, and so ntf cannot be changed.  Is there any way around this in scipy?

Comment: Do you want ntf to be the gain of the filter?

Comment: I am interested in the impulse response of L.  I can calculate L by hand of course but I assume there is a way to do it in scipy